# Drawing a contiguous spiral?

Tags: c++, opengl

Here's a function that I wrote that draws a spiral:

```
void drawSpiral(GLfloat x1, GLfloat y1, GLfloat radius)
{
    int lineAmount = 500;
    GLfloat piMultiplier = 10.0f * 3.141592654;

    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    for (int i = 0; i <= lineAmount; i++) 
    {
        GLfloat theta = i/lineAmount*piMultiplier;
        GLfloat x = x1 + (radius*cos(i*piMultiplier/lineAmount));
        GLfloat y = y1 + (radius*sin(i*piMultiplier/lineAmount));

        glVertex2f(x, y);

        radius += 1;
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

The problem is that the spiral gets drawn as dotted lines instead of one contiguous line.

[image: spiral-lines]

I can get a continuous line using GL_LINE_LOOP instead of GL_LINES, but that (understandably) draws a line from the middle to outside of the spiral. So I know my logic is good, I'm just not sure whats the opengl way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either do:

- `GL_LINES` with an array of vertex like: `[start, end, start, end...]`. In this case, you would need a very redundant array like: `[A, B, B, C, C, D]`
- `GL_LINE_STRIP` with an array of vertices like `[A, B, C, D]`
- `GL_LINE_LOOP` will create a line between the final vertex and the first, I don't think that's what you want.

In short, use `GL_LINE_STRIP` rather than `GL_LINES`.

Comment: No, just replace `glBegin(GL_LINES);` with `glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);`